# Nested loops to read files

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am new in python and I am little bit confused about some specific usages of nested loops.

For example I have two files(*file1* and *file2*). *File1* contains some text lines:

```
line1
line2
```

and *file2* also contains some text:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

and my script is:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        for line in file1:
            for line2 in file2:
                print(line2),
```

so I expected output like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line1
line2
line3 
line4
line5
```

but my output actually is:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Can someone explain me why only internal loop was executed?
Am I missing something?
There is no problem when I store the content of files to lists.

Answer (score 0):

> why only internal loop was executed?

This observation is wrong. Both loops were executed.

`file` objects are generators. They can only be iterated through once then they are considered to be consumed (ie empty).

In the first iteration of the outer loop, `file2` was not yet consumed, so the internal loop is able to be executed as expected.

From the second iteration of the outer loop, `file2` is totally consumed (ie empty), hence the outer loop has nothing to execute and is essentially equivalent to:

```
for line in file1:
    for line2 in []:
        print(line2)
```

To remedy this, use `.readlines` to get the files' content as lists.

BTW, you can have multiple `with` statements on a single line, hence saving an indentation level. Also, `'r'` is the default mode:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but I have one more question. What if I want to avoid `readlines()` function, because I want handle big files without worrying about memory problems. For example I just want to print equal lines from both files, so I just add condition `if line == line2:` into second for loop. Is there some more effective way, how to read this both files without using `readlines()` function?

Comment: @Stepmir see [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)